# CollectionCell width calculated based on the intrinsic width of a UILabel inside of it rather than the implemented sizeForItem method

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

Attached is a screenshot of when i run it on a physical device iPhone 6s, 
Also i've added a screenshot of the used constraints

And here's the code of the sizeForItem:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = topicCollectionView.frame.width / 2
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 260)
}
```

Comment: This is the first time using stackOverflow for questions, and apparently i didn't attach the screenshots properly.